# An infinite sum

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Can someone help me prove the below? Thanks.

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\Gamma (k)^2}{\prod _{m=1}^k (x \Gamma (m)+m)}=\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:
$$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)\Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{x}=\dfrac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x+1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not too difficult to prove by induction that:
$$ \frac{1}{x}-\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\Gamma(k)^2}{\prod_{m=1}^{k}(x\,\Gamma(m)+m)}=\frac{\Gamma(N+1)}{x\,\prod_{m=1}^{N-1}(x\,\Gamma(m)+m)}\tag{1}$$
holds for every $N\geq 1$. For any $x>0$ the RHS of $(1)$ goes to zero extremely fast as $N\to +\infty$, hence the claim follows.